# How to create a war file from git project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, war

I want to create a war file from an existing github project. The problem is I couldnt open this project with neither Eclipse nor Intellij. I want to upload this project to Google App Engine.Is there a problem with project directories or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the project;

```
https://github.com/zackzachariah/Foursquare-Welcome-Screen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the zip of the git, Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master.zip; unzip it to folder Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master; cd into that folder and run jar -cvf ../Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master.war *; now the war is in the same folder as Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master.

However, WAR is a specific format for deployment to a J2EE servet engine and requires a certain configuration to work.  Notice that in Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master there is a war folder.  That is already a deployable WAR. It could be turned into a .war file and an application server would unbundle it into the form it is now in, but that is not necessary.

Better to take a look at Foursquare-Welcome-Screen-master/README.md which has full instructions for setting it up on your own venue at Google App Engine.